# Redisearch prefix search always returns max 200 for total for multiple fields index

Tags: python, redis, redisearch

Using python RediSearch client to connect to RediSearch and doing a prefix search which should match 300 documents it only returns 200 if there is another TagField in the index:

```py
from redisearch import Client, Query, TextField, TagField

client = Client('myindex')
client.create_index([TextField('username'), TagField('age')])

# add 300 documents
for i in range(300):
    client.add_document(i, username='user%s' % i, age=i)

res = client.search(Query("@username:user*"))

assert res.total == 300 # this is always 200 no matter how many documents you add.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Search Query Syntax: Prefix matching](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/Query_Syntax.html#prefix_matching)

> A few notes on prefix searches: As prefixes can be expanded into many
>   many terms, use them with caution. There is no magic going on, the
>   expansion will create a Union operation of all suffixes.
>
> As a protective measure to avoid selecting too many terms, and block
>   redis, which is single threaded, there are two limitations on prefix
>   matching:
>
> Prefixes are limited to 2 letters or more. You can change this number
>   by using the MINPREFIX setting on the module command line.
>
> **Expansion is limited to 200 terms or less**. You can change this number
>   by using the MAXEXPANSIONS setting on the module command line.

See [Run-time configuration: MAXEXPANSIONS](https://github.com/RediSearch/RediSearch/blob/master/docs/Configuring.md#maxexpansions) for how to configure.

Comment: Any suggestions for this question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59530799/redisearch-aggregate-return-top-5-of-each-group @LeoMurillo

Comment: You got it! :-)